# The path x is already mapped in workspace x. git tf checkin having Eclipse TFS path mapped

Tags: eclipse, macos, version-control, tfs, git-tf

On trying to checkin using git-tf, I got the following error:
git-tf: The path /Users/xxx/.git/tf/612ef50 is already mapped in workspace MacBook-Pro;DOMAIN\USER.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the conflict after a few hours by simply removing the mapping on Eclipse TFS to a parent folder of my project and the conflict was resolved.

Only specific projects and sub projects are being managed via Eclipse i.e. My android projects.
My Xcode projects are managed via GIT-TF.
The projects don't need to share a common parent folder.